# node-xlsx parse and paste an excel with the following style

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel

I am parsing my excel named `parsed.xls` with the following code

```
var xlsx = require('node-xlsx').default;
const workSheetsFromFile = xlsx.parse(__dirname + '/parsed.xls');
console.dir(workSheetsFromFile[0].data, {depth: null});
```

If I do this, I get a following array like:

```
 [
  [ <1 empty item>, 'Остаточная ведомость за 30.11.2023' ],
  [],
  [
    'Склад',
    'Гр.',
    'Код',
    'Наименование',
    'Ед.\nизм.',
    'Цена',
    'Сальдо на конец периода',
    <1 empty item>,
    'Ставка \nНДС'
  ],
  [ <6 empty items>, 'Кол-во', 'Сумма' ],
  [ '001.9', '1080', <4 empty items>, 1, 10.94 ],
  [
    '001.9',
    '70000999',
    '00053009',
    'ШКАФ МЕТ ИЗ Б/У 1000Х600Х1470ММ',
    'шт.',
    10.94,
    1,
    10.94
  ],...
```

The excel originally looks like this

[image]

Then I try to copy this into a new excel with such as

```
var xlsx = require('node-xlsx').default;
var { writeFile } = require('node:fs');

const data = [
  [ '', 'Остаточная ведомость за 30.11.2023' ],
  [],
  [
    'Склад',
    'Гр.',
    'Код',
    'Наименование',
    'Ед.\nизм.',
    'Цена',
    'Сальдо на конец периода',
    '',
    'Ставка \nНДС'
  ]
];
var buffer = xlsx.build([{name: 'mySheetName', data: data}]); // Returns a buffer

writeFile('message.xls',new Uint8Array( buffer), (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('The file has been saved!');
});
```

Yet I get a look similar to following:

[image]

So basically, the parser works but I have no style on it. How can I style this? Is it possible with this `node-xlsx` npm ? Helps are appreciated..